# How to scan an array and compare an input to the elements of the array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm trying to make a decimal to binary converter and this part of code is just a test sample. In this test program, I want to print out each element of the array and I just can't seem to make the program do that.

Here is my current code:

```
int[] nums = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    int dec;
    int out = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type decimal number.");
    dec = scan.nextInt();

    for( nums[out] = nums[out] ; out < 16 ; out++ );
    {
            System.out.println(out + "\n");//I want to print each element just to test my code .
    }
```

This is the output I get:

```
16
```

Where I should be getting this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting only 16 because there is a **;** at the end of for loop.

> for( nums[out] = nums[out] ; out < 16 ; out++ );

If you remove it, ur code will should work. By the way you should consider changing the code as PNS suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print contents of the `nums` array, just initialize the `out` parameter in the `for` loop:

```
for (int out = 0; out < nums.length ; out++);
{
   System.out.println(nums[out] + "\n");
}
```

If you want to print the number read via `Scanner`, do that directly:

```
System.out.println(dec + "\n");
```

The above, of course, does not do any conversion, nor does it do any comparison, so if something like that is required, the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: It underlines "out" in the println statement an gives the following error: "out cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: If you run the code as per the answer above, there is no error. If you try to print `out` outside the `for` loop, of course it will not recognize it.